# Which is more reliable to find process start time "/proc/pid" creation time or "ps ef" command

Tags: linux, process, pid

i have been trying to understand what time a particular hung cron process was started in my linux server.

I had checked this by looking at the time at which /proc/pid was created and also by ps ef command.

But sometimes the pid directory creation time and the process stime in ps is different. The time that the cron should run and what the ps command shows match.

Can someone help me out here, which is the most trusted method to check for a process start time and why are these both different.

Answer (score 0):

According to old [Red Hat answer](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=155658) about `/proc/PID` attributes:

> The files in /proc have no existence of their own.  They are ephemera,
> invented on the spur of the moment when you look at them, forgotten
> once you look away.  The only time that has any meaning for those
> files is "right now".
>
> So the 2.4 behaviour is not a bug.  The 2.6 behaviour is nothing more
> than an artifact of the different way that those files are getting
> cached there after they are first referenced; fork a process, wait an
> hour and then query /proc, and you'll find that the timestamps are
> "now"; they were invented when you first looked at /proc, *not* when
> the process was created.  They have nothing to do with the process
> itself.
>
> So it is inappropriate to assign any significance to the timestamps in
> /proc; they mean nothing, and are vulnerable to change.

So it's more reliable to trust output of `ps`.